# No route matches in Rails 3.0.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Been staring at this problem for a while now. Here's the error I'm getting when I try to view the page.

```
No route matches {:action=>"confirm", :controller=>"locations"}
```

This is what I have in the view.

```
<%= form_for(@location, :url => { :action => :confirm }) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

And I think my routes file is set up correctly.

```
Finder::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :locations do
    member do 
      post :confirm
    end
  end

  root :to => 'locations/index'
end
```

Any ideas?

**Updated:**

Ran rake routes and get what I think is correct.

```
confirm_location POST   /locations/:id/confirm(.:format) {:action=>"confirm", :controller=>"locations"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can debug your routes easily in the future by running `$ rake routes` and looking at the output. ;)

I *think* what is happening is that your `post :confirm` isn't registering the route you're expecting. In the guides, `match` and it's brethren accept a string as a URL segment like so:

```
resources :locations do
  member do
    post 'confirm'
  end
end
```

Note that "confirm" is now a string instead of a symbol.

If this doesn't help, run `$ rake routes` and tack the output onto your question.

**Update**

After seeing your rake output, I think that you just need to specify the POST method on your `form_for`:

```
<%= form_for(@location, :url => { :action => :confirm }, :method => :post) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

You can also make this more readable using that helper method that Rails defines:

```
<%= form_for(@location, :url => confirm_location_path(@location), :method => :post) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, @coreyward. Rewriting how you suggested seems to have exposed the problem. `@location` doesn't have an id yet, so it makes sense that the route wouldn't work.

Comment: @Garrett: That'd make sense. Glad we got it figured out. You can possibly remove the `method` parameter to the `form_for`. It's not needed for resourceful-routed objects, though you *might* find it is if you're using a custom `url` parameter. A bit of poking once you have things working should tell you definitively either way.

Answer (score 1):

Did you define the `confirm` action in your LocationsController?

Comment: Good guess, but this isn't the problem; he's getting the error when he views the form because the implicit `url_for` isn't able to find a route defined for the parameters he specified.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a `:method => :post` to your `form_for`

```
<%= form_for(@location, :url => { :action => :confirm }, :method => :post) do |f| %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that form_for doesn't sneak in a hidden field with _method=put if you have declared the route as accepting only post in your routes file.